# How to fetch individual company name from a website in selenium

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I'm a noob in selenium with python. I'm trying to fetch some data from this link: http://www.dcciinfo.com/dirinfo/companies/all/10888?start=30, the data i wanna fetch is the company name and and put in an excel, also copy the link and paste it in the same excel column. Next it should proceed to the next company mentioned. Can somebody please help me out and give me some tips how to move from one company to another . I'm unable to identify by using id, xpath. The same has to be repeated din the next page and be done for all the 65 pages.

I have just written the basic code for in selenium:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.dcciinfo.com/dirinfo/companies/all/10888?start=30") # Load page
x=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/form/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .find_elements_by_xpath this will return element list. You can then loop through it. Also use this `//*[@id="content"]/form/div/div/div[1]/a` instead of your current xpath

Comment: Nope it does not click the element, using the xpath which u have given!! when you say loop, what variable should i loop ?

Comment: @EbrahimShariff this gives you A LIST of elements. Use for loop on 'x' and the use click method on its elements

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a CSS selector to XPath. This should head you in the right direction.

```
browser.get("http://www.dcciinfo.com/dirinfo/companies/all/10888?start=30") # Load page
companies = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.title > a")
for company in companies:
    company.text // put this in Excel as the company name
    company.get_attribute("href") // put this in Excel as the company URL
```

`companies` is a list of the `A` tags that contain the data you want. The `href` contains the URL for the company and `.text` contains the name of the company.